# Zero element of a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $S\subseteq R$ a subring of $R$.

If $0_{R}\in R$ denotes the zero element of $R$ and $0_{S}\in S$ the zero element of $S$. Then, $0_{R} = 0_{S}$.

**Proof:**

We know $b + 0_{S} = b$, $\forall$ $b\in S$. And also  $S\subseteq R$, then $b$, $0_{S}$ $\in R$

Adding $-b \in R$ in both sides we obtain:

$$-b+(b + 0_{S}) = -b + b \Longrightarrow (-b+b) + 0_{S} = -b + b \Longrightarrow 0_{R} + 0_{S}= 0_{R} \text{ (1)}$$

But $0_{R}$ is the zero element of R, then $0_{R} + 0_{S}= 0_{S}$ $(2)$

By (1) and (2), we conclude $0_{R} = 0_{S}$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me. But consider that $S$ may be exactly $\{0_S\}$, in which case $b = 0_S$ is the only possibility! With this in mind, it would be easier for you to consider the following identity using $0_S$ only: $0_S + 0_S = 0_S$. Then ask yourself, what elements $r \in R$ have the property that $r + r = r$? (It turns out this is quite restrictive!)

Comment: Nice point of view! Only $r = 0_{R}$ have that property. Thanks for your help!